# Reporting automated malicious activities on webserver

Tags: httpserver

I have been hosting a personal webserver for over a week now, and I have logged some suspicious requests. For my understanding these are automated scanning tools, vulnerability scanners, trying to find exploits in my backend. Below are some of the requested URIs I've logged

```
/test
/testing
/wordpress
/wp
/wp-content/themes/seotheme/db.php?u
/ALFA_DATA/alfacgiapi/perl.alfa
/alfacgiapi/perl.alfa
/wp-plain.php
//2019/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//2020/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//blog/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//cms/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//news/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//shop/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//site/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//sito/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//test/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//web/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//website/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//wordpress/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//wp/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//wp1/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//wp2/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml
//xmlrpc.php?rsd
/robots.txt
/wp-login.php
/humans.txt
/ads.txt
/sitemap.xml
/.env
/.git/config
/admin/server/php/
/assets/admin/js/filemanager/dialog.php
/assets/filemanager/dialog.php
/assets/global/plugins/jquery-file-upload/server/php/
/assets/jquery-file-upload/server/php/
/assets/plugins/filemanager/dialog.php
/assets/plugins/jquery-file-upload/server/php/
/editor/plugins/filemanager/dialog.php
/filemanager/dialog.php
/fileupload/server/php/
/media/filemanager/dialog.php
/server/php/
/upload/server/php/
/webroot/filemanager/dialog.php
/.vscode/sftp.json
/sftp-config.json
/cpanel/
```

Now, the server I am running is written by myself in C++, secured with all the measures I could find and forwarded through cloudflare, so I am not afraid of being successfully attacked (also all the above requests were served 404 according to my logs). Nevertheless I have IP addresses of the computers that made these requests and my question is whether I should report them somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience reporting such things is a waste of time. The source IPs are almost universally other compromised computers/cloud slices and generally part of large netblocks of IP addressed belonging to large ISPs, Amazon, Google, DigitalOcean, Microsoft, etc. If you send them your log extracts some will send you back a boilerplate response but take no action whatever (judging from the continuation of periodic similar requests from the same IPs). Some don't respond to email addresses listed in whois, but require you to go through some  "abuse api", which - even when you go to the trouble - gets you the same lack of response.

The problem is there is no penalty to the ISPs for hosting attackers. The rent pays the same. In fact, if they shut off these IPs the rent goes down. Your best bet is to filter the requests yourself and block the extremely frequent/obnoxious ones with iptables.